# I'm looking for a word that means "Intended for particular use"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am trying to come up with a word that means something is intended to be used with something else, like **"proprietary"** without the legal connotation, for example after-market car parts. They're not proprietary, but they will only fit an '89 Cutlass, etc.

"Intended" is too broad, "integrated", "co-engineered", "related", "matching", "custom" all miss the mark.

"The Widget Co fasteners only work with these hinges, they're proprietary".

**Edit** more info:

Thanks FumbleFingers for "dedicated to/specifically made for", that is the right idea. I want to boil it to one word (if it's out there) to use in as a bullet point or - if I'm lucky - a mnemonic.

Comment: A [**bolt-on**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bolt-on), for example, is something *added to a ​main ​product, ​service, or ​plan as a ​smaller, ​extra ​part or ​feature, ​especially in ​business*. For your context I think you'd be better of with a phrase, such as *...they're **dedicated to/specifically made for** this job*.

Comment: Technically, *ad hoc* would work, but it carries the wrong connotation.

Comment: I would use _product-specific_, even though it isn't the kind of simple term you would prefer. Many third-party accessories for particular editions of Apple products, for example, are identified as iPhone 6S–specific, iMac Reina–specific, or the like, when they are designed to work with only a particular model of a product. As FumbleFingers observes, the word _dedicated_ indicates a similar specificity of functionality and may be a better choice in certain contexts.

Comment: +1 for "specific". *Definition: having a special application, bearing, or reference; relating to one thing and not others; ​particular*.

Comment: They're probably too similar to "matching," which you say doesn't work, but "..., they're matched" or " ... they're paired" are pretty close, I think.

Comment: Or if there’s any room for figurative extension, you could consider “…, they’re [soulmates](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/soul-mate)."

Comment: Just because I work in a field where there are [ASICs](http://beta.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/application-specific%20integrated%20circuit), I am compelled to suggest *application-specific.*

Comment: +1 again for "specific", which is used all the time. "The cases are specific to the iPhone 6s".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use **specialized**.  "The Widget Co fasteners are *specialized* for these hinges, they work only with them" or "The Widget Co fasteners work only with these hinges, they're **specialized**".

Comment: "specialty" is another word, but it would refer to a tight range of products - where specialized might be better if they are more single application ?  Like: Acme Refrirator supply makes specialty hardware for use within low temperature freezer boxes, including specialized intake valves for each brand and model number.

Answer (score 5):

You could consider using [***tailor-made***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/tailor-made) which means the following:

> Made, adapted, or suited for a ***particular purpose*** or person

Also [***unique***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/unique):

> Being the only one of its kind; unlike anything else:

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

> The Widget Co fasteners only work with these hinges, they're ***tailor-made/unique***.

Answer (score 0):

[ad hoc](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/ad_hoc) (adj & adv), according to Oxford Dictionary Online:

> formed, arranged, or done for a particular purpose only